# Simple Excel VBA macro failing

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following simple macro to copy data from a closed worksheet. The code runs fine from the VBA editor but fails with a subscript error when run from Excel via macro. The paste special statement appears to be the issue.

I just can't see where the problem is, can anyone help?

```
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Set wsMaster = Worksheets("Master Data")
Dim lastrow As Long

Dim Files As String
   Files = "Download.xlsx"

Dim filepath As String
   filepath = "C:\users\ms612533\desktop\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wsMaster.Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.Clear

Workbooks.Open (filepath & Files)
lastrow = Worksheets("Global").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Worksheets("Global").Range("A1:V" & lastrow).Copy _
wsMaster.Range("B1")
Worksheets("Global").Range("CV1:cv" & lastrow).Copy
wsMaster.Range("a1").PasteSpecial (xlValues)**
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Call CloseAll

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub CloseAll()
' Close all but the active workbook

 Dim wkbk As Workbook

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 For Each wkbk In Application.Workbooks
     If wkbk.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
         wkbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
     End If
 Next

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this *`he code runs fine from the VBA editor but fails with a subscript error when run from Excel via macro.`*? It unclear to me. Also please note that `Workbooks.Open` actually opens a workbook so you are not really *`copying data from a closed worksheet.`*. There are [other ways to get data from closed workbooks without opening them](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/various-ways-to-pull-data-from-another-workbook-closedopened/).

Comment: The macro has a keyboard shortcut. When run using this shortcut it fails as described. When run directly from the module inside the editor it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong with the `PasteSpecial` line: when I use the macro recorder, I get something like this:

```
wsMaster.Range("a1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I think we can ignore the parameters after the first. Then we have this:

```
wsMaster.Range("a1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Note that there are no parens (`()`) around the arguments: `PasteSpecial` doesn't return anything so it should be treated like a function. That's probably where the subscript issue is coming from.

Also notice the parameter, which comes from the `xlPasteType` enum, is a little different from the value you had.

Comment: That doesn't work either I'm afraid but the plot thickens. If I call the macro from Excel using the shortcut but then step through it in debug it works fine. If I call it from the shortcut but don't set any breakpoints then it fails. This is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to work fine when calling the macro from a button, but it doesn't work from a shortcut. I'll put it down to an Excel 'feature' and move on.